# OLAP Calculated Member with hierarchy

Tags: excel, mdx, olap-cube

My company uses `OLAP` for our Sales data, and recently changed the hierarchy of categories, business units and divisions, but it wasn't reflect on the `OLAP cube`.

I'm trying to reflect this new hierarchy on the client side for the reports, and have been able to group/aggregate the categories into the new business units, but with this method I can't drill down into the lower levels, no "+" on the pivot table to open into the categories.

Is it possible to have this kind of grouping and be able to drill down?

Diagram of pivot table:

> 10 - ALIMENTAR
>
> > **03 - SOFT DRINKS**
> >     **03 - HARD DRINKS**
> >     03 - BEBIDAS
> >
> > > 0300 - MOVIMENTOS À UN 03
> > >       0301 - SUMOS E NECTARES
> > >       0302 - REFRIGERANTES
> > >       0303 - CERVEJAS
> > >       0304 - ÁGUAS
> > >       0305 - V.CLASSIF.NAC/ESTRAN
> > >       0306 - VINHOS CORRENTES
> > >       0307 - ESPIRIT/ESPUM/FORTIF

Using `OLAP PivotTable Extensions` I created the calculated members.

Member 1:

Name: [Comercial].[Comercial Standard].[Todas as Direcções Comerciais].[10 - ALIMENTAR].[03 - SOFT DRINKS]

```
AGGREGATE({[Comercial].[Comercial Standard].[Categoria].&[0301], 
 [Comercial].[Comercial Standard].[Categoria].&[0302], 
 [Comercial].[Comercial Standard].[Categoria].&[0303], 
 [Comercial].[Comercial Standard].[Categoria].&[0304]})
```

Member 2:

Name: [Comercial].[Comercial Standard].[Todas as Direcções Comerciais].[10 - ALIMENTAR].[03 - HARD DRINKS]

```
AGGREGATE({[Comercial].[Comercial Standard].[Categoria].&[0305], 
 [Comercial].[Comercial Standard].[Categoria].&[0306], 
 [Comercial].[Comercial Standard].[Categoria].&[0307]})
```

I'm using Office 2010 and Windows 7 (Office 2013 is not available).

Comment: Is PowerPivot an option?

Comment: I've made the change using PowerPivot, the problem is when I import the data it goes to one table, one very big table, about 50 columns/fields and 12 million records without sales by store, if I had the store dimension it goes to several hundred million records, which the PC doesn't have the memory to handle.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create a user defined hierarchy in the dimension and then re-deploy the cube in order for Excel Pivot tables to properly work with this.

The documentation for setting up user defined hierarchies can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365350.aspx.

Comment: @HugoCaeiro In that case, when you access the cube, you will have to live with what the designer of the cube prepared for you, and if there are no user hierarchies in the cube, then Excel does not show any.